# How to retrieve the old commit before rebase

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Say, I am working on a branch called 'latest'. After finishing the task, I commit the work. When I rebase the changes from 'master' branch onto 'latest' branch, during conflict-resolution, I accidentally accept all the changes from master & as a result, by the end, when the rebase is completed, I have lost a lot of my work done in 'latest'.

Considering that I rebased within 'latest' branch, are the commits for the work I did, overwritten by the conflict resolutions I accepted? Is/ are my previous (original) commits gone? And if not, how can I retrieve them please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original commits you made in the `latest` branch should still be accessible in the git reflog.  The current `latest` branch though now has new, rewritten commits.  You could try to sift through the reflog, though the fastest way out of this might be to just hard reset `latest` to the remote tracking branch `origin/latest`:

```
# from latest
git reset --hard origin/latest
```

This option assumes that, after you made the commits in question, you pushed to the remote, thereby updating the (local) tracking branch `origin/latest`.  If so, the tracking branch should still look the same as before the rebase.

If you *didn't* push your local branch after making the commits, then the reflog may still be able to help you.  Type `git reflog`.  Then, find the commit which was the HEAD of your branch before the botched rebase.  You may use the commit message to help you there.  Once you have the SHA-1 of that commit, again do a hard reset:

```
# from latest
git reset --hard <SHA-1 of your old HEAD>
```

Comment: Thats the problem. I didn't push my working branch 'latest' to remote origin. It was all local.

Comment: @Kayote I have also given you an option using the reflog in this case.

Comment: Thanks, the issue isn't that I cannot take the HEAD back, its that I cannot cherrypick the commits on top, because the old commits no longer exist?

Comment: @Kayote The old commits are still part of Git's object model, and the pointers between them are also still there.

Comment: They still exist... you can see what they are using reloj. Normally you take back work that is not correct, like what You are describing, by resetting... but if you want to apply on top with cherry-pick, you can do it.

Comment: I think @eftshift0 meant `reflog`

Comment: Was writing from my cellphone.... dictionary kicked in. Ugh. Yes, `git reflog`

Comment: @eftshift0 For what it's worth, I wrote this entire answer on a Samsung Android phone `:-)`

Comment: It's not an excuse.... I normally pay attention to this when I'm writing on my cell phone.... _but_ one word can slip by here or there, right?

Comment: I am not criticizing you in any way, just commenting that I also sometimes contribute via a cell phone.